# HTML 5 - Sneaky stuff

Tags: html, tags, standards, wiki, w3c

**HTML 5** is the new W3C definition for HTML and will likely represent the direction the internet goes as people find the next killer apps that work in it.

There are the much publicized 'public' coding features like the `<video>` tag, but I'm wondering what low-level coding tricks people have found so far that could be important, useful, interesting or all of the above.

***Some examples I've come across thus far:***

Drag-and-drop events that control data transfer - eg:

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event)
{
   event.dataTransfer.setData("image/png", slides.imageRep());
   event.dataTransfer.setData("slides", slides.serializedRep());
   // etc.
}, false)
```

2-dimensional and 3-dimensional graphics through extension of the `<canvas>` element.

Context-aware html blocks

(as a bonus - the obselecense of the `<applet>` and `<marquee>` tags - woohoo!)

`<ruby>` tag for ideographs

and I'm not sure if this is new, but the `<progress>` tag - these dynamically updateable tags are going to make the web a richer experience.

Anyone played with these and found some interesting examples of them put together? Some demo code perhaps?

Comment: Please make this question "community wiki". You aren't planning to eventually accept an answer, are you?

Comment: well if there's some definitive answer, sure, but otherwise I guess it's a wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nice samples on [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/)

From the about page:

> These experiments were created by
>   designers and programmers from around
>   the world using the latest open
>   standards, including HTML5, Canvas,
>   SVG, and more

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/), from Mozilla Labs - it is a code editor written entirely in JavaScript, using Canvas.

Also, it may not be a "sample" per se, but the [Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) on the Mozilla Developer Center is a very good introduction to the `<canvas />` element.